# Find number of weekdays/weekends in a given date range

Tags: ms-access, vba, date

I'm trying to find some VBA code to determine the number of week days and weekend days in a given date range using Access VBA.

For example:

```
Begin Date - 1/1/2012
End Date - 1/31/2012
```

Result should be:

```
Week days - 22
Weekend days - 9
```

Can anyone help out with this?

Comment: Can you use the NETWORKDAYS function?

Pseudo Code:

TotalDays via a Datediff of two dates

Run NETWORKDAYS function on two dates

Minus Workdays from Totaldays for weekend days.

Comment: The NETWORKDAYS function is a valuable Excel Worksheet function, but it does not exist in VBA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two functions will calculate the number of weekdays and weekend days:

```
Function NumWeekendDays(dBegin As Date, dEnd As Date) As Long
    Dim iPartial As Integer
    Dim lBeginDay As Long
    Dim lNumWeekendDays As Long

    iPartial = DateDiff("d", dBegin, dEnd + 1) Mod 7
    lBeginDay = 6 - DatePart("w", dBegin, vbMonday)

    lNumWeekendDays = (DateDiff("d", dBegin, dEnd + 1) \ 7) * 2
    If iPartial > 0 And lBeginDay - iPartial < 0 Then
        If lBeginDay = -1 Then
            lNumWeekendDays = lNumWeekendDays + 1
        ElseIf iPartial - lBeginDay = 1 Then
            lNumWeekendDays = lNumWeekendDays + 1
        Else
            lNumWeekendDays = lNumWeekendDays + 2
        End If
    End If

    NumWeekendDays = lNumWeekendDays

End Function

Function NumWeekDays(dBegin As Date, dEnd As Date) As Long
    NumWeekDays = DateDiff("d", dBegin, dEnd + 1) - NumWeekendDays(dBegin, dEnd)
End Function
```

Note: I found it simplest to calculate the partial-week weekend days by calculating the `lBeginDay` variable so that if the start date was Monday, `lBeginDay == 5`... if the start date was Friday, `lBeginDay == 1`, etc. Other variations should also work.

Comment: There is a bug in this sample code. It returns a 2 if the end date is Friday. "If iPartial > 0 And lBeginDay - iPartial <**=** 0 Then" should be "If iPartial > 0 And lBeginDay - iPartial < 0 Then " When "<=" is changed to just "<" it works great.